# Product measure of two different measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a probability measure space:
$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},Q)$ and random variable $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $X(\omega) =\omega$ and consequently $P_X=Q$

Now a new probability measure  $((\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{B}^{2})$ with property :
$$ P(A \times B)=Q(A)Q(B)$$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$ i.e the product measure $(P = Q \otimes Q)$ with random variable $Y:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}:Y(\omega_{1},\omega_{2})=\omega_{1}$

Showing that $P_X = P_Y=Q$ the only thing that someone can do is to take
the intersection of $P(A) \cap P(B) =P_X \cap P_Y= (\omega_{1},\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3},\dots)=\omega_{1}=Q$

or I am wrong since this property

$Y(\omega_{1},\omega_{2})=\omega_{1}$ holds ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If those two probabilities are the same

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make any sense of the statements in your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can prove that $P_X=P_Y=Q$.

Since $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with $X(\omega) =\omega$, we have $P_X$ is a probability defined on $\{A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B} \} = \mathcal{B}$  and, for every $A \in \mathcal{B}$,
$$P_X(A) = Q(X^{-1}(A)) = Q(A)$$

On the other hand,  $Y:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, with $Y(\omega_{1},\omega_{2})=\omega_{1}$, we have $P_Y$ is a probability defined on $$\{A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : Y^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}^2 \}= \{A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : A \times \mathbb R \in \mathcal{B}^2 \} = \mathcal{B}$$  and, for every $A \in \mathcal{B}$, $$P_Y(A) = (Q\otimes Q)(Y^{-1}(A)) = (Q\otimes Q)(A \times \mathbb R)= Q(A)Q(\mathbb R)=Q(A)$$
where we used that $Q(\mathbb R)=1$, because $Q$ is a probability.

Comment: Why my effort is wrong?

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis , There is no sense in " $P(A) \cap P(B)$".  $P(A)$ and $P(B)$  are numbers in $[0,1]$. We can not take intersection of them. In the same way, we can not write $P_X \cap P_Y$, because $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are not sets.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ramiro